# How to convert the character into dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a variable `"i"` which I am using to access various `data.frame` using `paste0` command like `paste0("sales_feed",i)`. The output which I am getting is `"sales_feed_1"`. But I want to use `data.frame` `"sales_feed_1"`. I have tried `as.data.frame(paste0("sales_feed_",i))`.

Comment: see function `get`: `get(paste0("sales_feed", i))`

Comment: thanks, you suggestion has worked. i have one more trouble suppose in the above table there is two column of first name and last name. i want to create a new column containing full name so i have written code get(paste0("sales_feed", i))$full_name <- paste0(get(paste0("sales_feed", i))$first_name,get(paste0("sales_feed", i))$last_name), then code is not working. if i am using paste0(get(paste0("sales_feed", i))$first_name,get(paste0("sales_feed", i))$last_name) i am getting result but unable to save in the column. do you have any solution for this.

Comment: maybe try `get(paste0("sales_feed", i))[, "last_name"]`

Comment: Thanks such quick reply, i am not finding problem in processing data of already column present but to create a new column like get(paste0("sales_feed", i))$full_name

Comment: you cannot use `get` and assign something to it afterwards (sorry I read your comment too quickly). Probably the simplest way would be to create a temporary `data.frame` and then rassign it to `paste0("sales_feed", i)` using `assign`